# Reading text from a text file and storing it in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

Is there any way to read from a text file and store the contents in a Jtable? I've got a text file that contains certain information about some processes. It's like a table that has columns and respective values. Is it possible to take the contents of the .txt file and display it in the form of Jtable? I'm using Eclipse and Window Builder.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible. If you want a better answer, I strongly suggest to start coding and if you get stuck post a specific question for a specific problem. This question is very broad. To get you going, take a look at the [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: @Robin I was wondering, is there any way to get text file's data in a 2d array? Please can you guide me on that?

Comment: Open a specific question for that with the code you tried and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the tutorials from Oracle:

- [Reading/writing text files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#textfiles)
- [JTable Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple)

When you get the data from the text file you would need to put it into a 2D Array and use that 2D array (along with the columnNames array) to create a new JTable Object. (more details are found in the JTable Tutorials)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I think it's gonna work for sure!