# Read txt and add in jtable

Tags: java, jtable

I am new to java and I need to create a program that reads text from a txt file and puts it into a jtable, the format in the txt file  will be like "b3:42".  And I need to read those and put b3 in the first column of the table and 42 in the next column. Could you help me ? And sorry for my english.

Comment: You can look at these two questions: [Reading text from a text file and storing it in Jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000568/reading-text-from-a-text-file-and-storing-it-in-jtable) [Read text file and display it in Jtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010776/read-text-file-and-display-it-in-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below code .

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;    
public class HelloWorld{
    private static final String FILENAME = "input.txt";
     public static void main(String []args){       
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String s;
            String[][] data = new String[2][2];

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
            int i = 0;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 data[i]= s.split(":");
                i++;
            }

           String column[]={"COL1","COL2"};
            JTable jt=new JTable(data,column);    
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
     }
}
```

Comment: So I've tried it and this is what I get :  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Comment: you need to set the index of data variable in your code  according to the input file columns and rows.            


**String[][] data = new String[2][2];**

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions

You can read txt file line by line using BufferedReader and related chained stream in this way:

```
public class TestSO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String line = "";
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("yourfile.txt")))){
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // Process the line

                }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to split your line into pieces you need you must use **line.split(":")** You get 2 tokens, the one before the colon and the one after it.

```
String tokens[] = line.split(":");
```

According to JTable documentation you can create a JTable as **JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)**

So you can use tokens you read and parsed above to create the rowData array.

Then create the array for the column names:

```
//headers for the table
String[] columns = new String[] {
    "Col1", "Col2"
};
```

At the end just creare the JTable passing it the arrays with data and column names:

```
//create table with data
JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```